# unable to change host name on Ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: 14.04, hostname

Here are the steps I followed:

1. Changed `/etc/hosts`:

   ```
   cat /etc/hosts

       127.0.0.1 localhost
       127.0.1.1 linux-vm
   ```
2. Change `etc/hostname`

   ```
   cat /etc/hostname

       linux-vm
   ```
3. Reboot

Still the TTy shows the old hostname:

[image]

How can I change it permanently?

Answer (score 3):

You may also need to use the systemd way of changing the hostname:

```
sudo hostnamectl --static set-hostname servername
```

Also Ubuntu has been including [`cloud-init`](https://cloud-init.io/) in its later distributions which provides control for setting up cloud instances - including setting the **hostname** - so even when you use all of the above to change the hostname and it still doesn't stick after a reboot then it's worth looking into whether cloud-init is installed. If it is you've got two options - either you can disable it (after making the hostname changes as above):

```
 sudo touch /etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled
```

Or you can create a new user-data file and reload the config - see the [cloud-init docs](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for details.

Comment: yep the cloud init was the reason for me

Answer (score 1):

Many virtual machine hosts will overwrite your /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts file upon every reboot to whatever is configured within their customer control panel.

If you can, configure your desired hostname within your VPS host's control panel.

An alternative option that many people use - despite being a bit of a hack - is to mark these files as *immutable* meaning that they are truly read-only (even by root).

This is a *file attribute*.  Linux filesystems allow many file attributes, but they are rarely used.  You modify them with the `chattr` command (short for "change attributes" - as opposed to `chmod` to change permissions or `chown` to change ownership).

To set a file as immutable:

```
chattr +i filename
```

To clear the immutable flag:

```
chattr -i filename
```

This approach is known to work on OpenVZ platforms, which are the platforms in which the /etc/hosts rewriting issue is most likely to occur.  If you have machine level virtualisation like Xen or KVM/Qemu, it's less likely to work.

Answer (score 0):

I tested right now I this is what I did apart from following your steps:

```
sudo nano /etc/hostname
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

I changed my host from `cyrex` to `cyrex2k` and rebooted and got:

```
cyrex@cyrex2k:~$ hostname
cyrex2k
cyrex@cyrex2k:~$ 

cyrex@cyrex2k:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   cyrex2k
```

So my recommendation is to check to see if the IP is validated against the domain name, just in case and also add what virtual environment you are using. I have had problems with VMware like this, so I moved to VirtualBox and QEMU (With KVM).